# Use of java in WMQ/WMB systems

Tags: java, ibm-mq, mq, messagebroker

I have been working with MQ and message brokers for quite some time. Just want to know in what ways java is helpful to run MQ systems

What's the relation of java in MQ systems? Will MQ have the java installable with it by default? Noticed the java directory in the MQ installable path, but still require clear explanation.

In what way Java is helpful to MQ or message broker? Is this purely java oriented as we see with activemq

This has been hitting my mind for quite a long time and it would really help to understand the mechanism behind MQ/Broker systems.

It would be greatly appreciable if someone could able to brief me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be great, if there is some insight on this  from T.Rob or Morag Hughson. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere MQ is not solely Java oriented, though it provides a Java API through which you can interact with your queue managers (put, get messages, and so on).

It has APIs for other programming languages as well, actually it is one of the main advantages of WebSphere MQ, that it provides a wide range of different APIs, so you can exchange messages between applications written in different languages using it.

Yes, the Java API is part of the base product.

Looking at the other part of your question, in WebSphere Message Broker applications you can implement message transformation logic in Java.

Comment: Thanks for showing some light on this Attila Repasi